# Getting "Server commited a protocol violation" after I moved website to another server

Tags: asp.net, https, nuget

I'm getting

```
---------------------------
NuGet Package Explorer
---------------------------
The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=Header name is invalid
```

when I try to download nuget package using NuGet Package Explorer.

This started happening after I moved the nuget server (asp.net web app) from azure website with **http** endpoint to my onpremises server with **https** endpoint.

It worked before using the same client (NuGet Package Explorer) so obiously the error is on the server.

I've tried to set useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" in web.config, but that does not helped

```
<system.net>
    <settings>
        <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I admit that network is for me the most misterious invention mankind ever made.

I asked my hosting provider to forward https://myserver/ url to port :443 instead of :80 and I've edited the bindings in IIS Manager for Default Web Site: 80 -> http and 443 -> https, and suddenly everything works.

Does anyone have explanation, pls?